sudo: inaccessible or not found after chmod 755
I have android 12 and muiu 14. I rooted the device with magisk and I have the latest version of magisk installed. I connected to my phone with adb shell and ran these commands. Because I was getting permission denied at sudo su
I did what this  thread did.
chmod 755 /
chmod 755 /bin
chmod 755 /lib

Then this error started happening:
/system/bin/sh: sudo: inaccessible or not found

How can I fix this ?
full log:
surya:/ $ sudo
/system/bin/sh: sudo: inaccessible or not found
127|surya:/ $ su -
Permission denied


su is not accessible by default on non-rooted Android devices. You need to root your device first.

already done. i have magisk and root. but with adb shell no permission @AndrewT.

chmod commands you've run make no sense. And there's no sudo in Android. Magisk only provides su binary. You can investigate "Permission denied" yourself. Check Magisk app if it reports rooted successfully. Check if magiskd is running: ps -A | grep magisk or pgrep -lf magisk. See where su is located: type su or which su. See its permissions with ls -l /path/to/su. Use a terminal emulator app to check if su works there.

I ran the chmod commands, without knowing what I am doing. Now I get : sudo: inaccessible or not found after I did the chmod 755. How can I fix my system back to normal ? please help
